# Changing one object changes all of them

Tags: java, oop, object, memory

I have created **two** classes, a class representing a **2-D point**, and a class representing a **line segment**, which stores two 2-D points. However, when I've made three separate line segment and change the value in one of them, using the function *setStartPoint(Point2D arg)* in the **LineSegment** class, it changes the value of all of them. I'm assuming it's because all the **Point2D** objects I've created for each **LineSegment** all point to the same object, however it seems to me that I'm declaring a new object every time (using new?). If anyone can spot my error and point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Please note, I just need an example for what I'm doing wrong, I don't want an exact answer for the line of code I should change or even where it is, just an idea for what I'm not implementing correctly, as it is for my computer science lab.

**Driver Class, written by Professor**

```
public class driver
{
    public static void lineSegmentDriver() 
    {
        LineSegment a = new LineSegment();
        LineSegment b = new LineSegment(new Point2D(1,1), new Point2D(2,2));
        LineSegment c = new LineSegment(b);

        a.setStartPoint(new Point2D(3,3));
        a.setEndPoint(new Point2D(4,4));

        System.out.println("Line a: " + a.toString());
        System.out.println("Line b: " + b.toString());
        System.out.println("Line c: " + c.toString());

        System.out.println("Line b's distance between points: " + b.distance());

        System.out.println("Does a equal b? " + a.equals(b));
        System.out.println("Does a equal c? " + a.equals(c));
        System.out.println("Does b equal c? " + b.equals(c));
    }
}
```

**LineSegment Class, written by me (comments removed)**

```
public class LineSegment
{
    private Point2D p1;
    private Point2D p2;

    public LineSegment()
    {
        this.p1 = new Point2D(0,0);
        this.p2 = new Point2D(0,0);
    }
    public LineSegment(Point2D p1, Point2D p2)
    {
        if (p1 == null || p2 == null)
        {
            this.p1 = new Point2D(0,0);
            this.p2 = new Point2D(0,0);
        }
        else
        {
            this.p1 = new Point2D(p1);
            this.p2 = new Point2D(p2);
        }
    }
    public LineSegment(LineSegment l)
    {
        this.p1 = new Point2D(l.p1);
        this.p2 = new Point2D(l.p2);
    }

    public Point2D getStartPoint()
    {
        Point2D varRet = new Point2D(p1);   
        return varRet;
    }
    public void setStartPoint(Point2D arg)
    {
        this.p1 = new Point2D(arg);
    }

    public Point2D getEndPoint()
    {
        Point2D varRet = new Point2D(p2);   
        return varRet;
    }
    public void setEndPoint(Point2D arg)
    {
        this.p2 = new Point2D(arg);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Line start (" + this.p1.getX() + "," + this.p1.getY() + ") and end (" +
            this.p2.getX() + "," + this.p2.getY() + ")";
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (o instanceof LineSegment && o != null)
        {
            LineSegment toCompare = (LineSegment) o;
            if (toCompare.p1.equals(this.p1) && 
                toCompare.p2.equals(this.p2))
                    return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public double distance()
    {
        return Math.sqrt(((this.p1.getY() - this.p2.getY()) * (this.p1.getY() - this.p2.getY())) +
                        ((this.p2.getX() - this.p1.getX()) *  (this.p1.getX() - this.p2.getX())));
    }
}
```

**Point2D Class, written by me**

```
public class Point2D
{
    private static int x;
    private static int y;

    public Point2D()
    {
        this.x = -1;
        this.y = -1;
    }
    public Point2D(int x, int y)
    {
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
    }
    public Point2D(Point2D point)
    {
        setX(point.x);
        setY(point.y);
    }

    public void setX(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getX()
    {
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setY(int y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getY()
    {
        return this.y;
    }

    public void resetToOrigin()
    {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }

    public void translate(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return Integer.toString(this.x) + "," + Integer.toString(this.y);
    }
    public boolean equals(Point2D pointObject)
    {
        if (this.x == pointObject.getX() &&
                this.y == pointObject.getY())
                return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have declared `x` and `y` `static` in your `Point2D`, which means that when you change them, they will affect class in general and not the specific `Point2D` instance.

Comment: Ughhh thanks. Can't believe I didn't spot that sooner, I thought somehow my Java development kit or environment was messed up somehow and declaring new Point2D objects in the same location in memory but it was really me saying for it to share primitives.